# php json_encode not escaping new lines

Tags: php, json

I am facing some issue with json_encode.

when i json_encode an array having new lines it is not escaping new lines instead it's removing \ and keeping n.

```
ex: $array = array('name'=> "some text \n\r text");
$results = json_encode($array);
```

it is saving `some text nr text` in database .

i am using `php 5.3.8`.

**edit:**

This is my original code i am using

```
$attr = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['key']); $i++){
    $attr[$_POST['key'][$i]] = $_POST['value'][$i];
}
echo json_encode(array('custom' => $attr));
```

these `POST` values getting from form.

Comment: Are you sure it's json_encode that's causing the problem? What do you get if you print_r($results); out in a browser? Ah and it should be \r\n...

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://codepad.org/Oya8CIMc) Are you sure you're looking at the raw output?

Comment: 1) shouldn't it be `\r\n`, 2) how do you send that string to your database? did you properly quote / escape the value (or at the very least use `addslashes()`) on it?

Comment: working fine with me, same PHP version. Any other operations you're doing before inserting in the databse?

Comment: thanks, when i do print_r($array) ouput is fine with new line, after json_encode() if i do json_decode() output is coming like above with out newlines..

Comment: same code is working fine with 5.3.3

Comment: So you're saying the following means you loose the newlines? `print_r( json_decode( json_encode( array('name'=> "some text \n text") ) ) );` - I can't reprocude that on my php version, I still retain the new lines.

Comment: @pebbl, when i do manual it is fine. only problem for post data.

Comment: @logicsinc I see so you are posting this data to your script and then you are loosing the newlines... ok well without a bit more information on exactly the system you have in place debugging could take a while. Is this posted data being put in to the database before you loose the newlines? If so I would most likely be at the point you are injecting those values in to your database query or the way your database is handling escaped characters... if you switch to using prepared statements as Truth suggests you should avoid any escaping or conversion issues entirely.

Comment: Please add you solution as an answer below (yes that works) and accept it as answer then (yes that works, too). That will correctly mark your question as solved. Do not put the solution in your question, move it into an answer instead ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this issue. it is not in json_encode problem. it is an error while saving to database.

The problem is **magic_quotes_gpc** enabled in server. in my application if magic_quotes enabled i am striping the slashes.

i disabled **magic_quotes_gpc**. working fine now.

Thanks for every body.

Comment: how did you disable it ?

Answer (score 10):

**[Newlines are not valid characters inside of JSON strings](http://json.org/)**. That's the expected behavior:

> #### char
>
> any Unicode character except " or \ or control-character
>
> - \"
> - \
> - /
> - \b
> - \f
> - \n
> - \r
> - \t
> - \u four-hex-digits

JSON escapes those control characters into those in the list.

So now we have `'\n'` (literally a backslash followed by 'n'), which, if not escaped properly, will be saved in the database as `n`. And **that** is the problem you're experiencing.

#### The Solution

Use prepared statements to properly escape any and all slashes in the strings you're storing in your database. That will save them as `'\n'`, which you can convert to `"\n"` when you retrieve your data.

Comment: Any suggestion for what he can do instead?

Comment: @andrewtweber: Use prepared statements properly?

Comment: Yes, but that would still escape the literal "\n" character to the escaped sequence '\n'... which my guess would mean there is something that is being done wrong on it's way to the database meaning not "a problem with json_encode". It is also just possible that the database viewer logicsinc is using doesn't support displaying \n properly ;)

Comment: @pebbl: No, as I said, that's the expected behavior. JSON doesn't support newlines, so it converts it into `'/n'`. If he uses prepared statements, that sequence will be saved, and it can be restored to `"/n"` once retrieved.

Comment: @Truth ah ok I missed the part where it converted it to `/n`, I thought it just removed the `\\`

Comment: @Truth I thought this question was talking about the behaviour of `json_encode` which at least for my version of php converts `"\n"` to `'\n'` (which is expected behaviour) - I don't see any mention of converting to `'/n'` in your post or on the link you've added - quite how this would resolve to just `n` at any point (definitely not expected behaviour) I'm not yet sure..

Comment: @pebbl: The database, when a slash is placed, if not properly escaped, will disappear. MySQL will convert `\n` to `n` when stored. That's why proper escaping (i.e. prepared statements) are required.

Comment: @Truth Yes, no worries, I understand that is definitely the issue now that the original poster has explained further... the database problem is what I explained above with my first comment. It seems we're on the same path, the mention of `'/n'` just baffled me is all :)

Answer (score 9):

I don't believe json_encode is your problem. My guess is your database is interpreting \ as the escape character, so it simply strips them out.

To combat that, simply escape the escape characters using [addslashes](https://www.php.net/addslashes):

```
$results=addslashes($results);
```

Comment: This solution works :
order = JSON.parse( '<?php echo addslashes( json_encode( $order ))?>' );

Comment: I gave you an upvote for this as real_escape_string fixed my problem

Comment: I searched a lot and this one was the best :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You could manually escape them:

```
$array = array('name'=> "some text \n\r text");

$results = json_encode(array_filter($array, function($arr) use ($array){
        return preg_replace('~\\[nrtfd]~', '\\\\$1', $arr);
}));

print_r($results);
```

You could extend your own json_encode function, and replace your uses of `json_encode` to `my_json_encode`:

```
function my_json_encode($json){
    $results = json_encode(array_filter($json, function($arr) use ($array){
        return preg_replace('~\\[nrtfd]~', '\\\\$1', $arr);
    }));

    return $results;
}

print_r($results);
```

FYI, the above returns: `{"name":"some text \n\r text"}` instead of `{"name":"some text nr text"}`

Comment: i can't do that manually.. i am using json_encode number places.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` as described in the PHP manual.

https://www.php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PHP_EOL` for a new line. Where to include new line depends on how you want. In the case below, i need a new line after the last closing square bracket and each curly bracket:

```
tit1: {
"prop1" : [ "", "", []], 
"prop2" : [ "", "", []]
}, 
tit2: {
"prop1" : [ "", "", []], 
"prop2" : [ "", "", []]
}
```

The function is

```
$jsonDataTxt = $this->own_format_json($jsonData);
file_put_contents("C:/Users/mm/Documents/Data.json", $jsonDataTxt);


function own_format_json($json, $html = false) {
        $tabcount = 0; 
        $result = ''; 
        $bnew = 0;
        $brack=0;  
        $tab = "\t"; 
        $newline = PHP_EOL; 
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($json); $i++) { 
            $char = $json[$i]; 
            if($char!==',' && $bnew===1) { $bnew=0; $result.=  $newline; } //insert new line after ], which is not proceeded by ,
            switch($char) { 
                case '{': 
                    $tabcount++; 
                    $result .= $char . $newline . str_repeat($tab, $tabcount); 
                    break; 
                case '}': 
                    $tabcount--; 
                    $result = trim($result) . $newline . str_repeat($tab, $tabcount) . $char . $newline; 
                    break; 
                case '[': 
                    $brack++; 
                    $result .= $char;// . $newline . str_repeat($tab, $tabcount); 
                    break; 
                case ']': 
                    $brack--;
                    $result .= $char;// . $newline . str_repeat($tab, $tabcount); 
                    if($brack===0) { $bnew=1; }
                    //echo "<br><br> case  ]  char=".$char.',   brack='.$brack. ",  bnew=".$bnew.",   result=".$result ; 
                    break; 
                case ',': 
                    $result .= $char;// . $newline . str_repeat($tab, $tabcount); 
                    if($bnew===1) { $bnew=0; $result.=  $newline; } //insert new line after ],
                    break; 
                case '"': 
                    $result .= $char; 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    $result .= $char; 
            } 
        } 
    return $result; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this command to clean the backslashes.

```
$info = file_get_contents('my_file.txt');
**$info = str_replace(array("r\n","\n", "\r"), "", $info);**    
$info = json_decode($info);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the simplest solution is to use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` (along with other flags, if you need them). You can learn more about these flags [in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

Regarding the original issue:

```
<?php
$tmp = array();

$tmp[1] = "test";
$tmp["ok"] = "this
seems to be
a
multiline
nightmare,
but
we
can manage it";

$conv = json_encode($tmp,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $conv;
?>
```

which outputs

```
{"1":"test","ok":"this\r\nseems to be\r\na\r\nmultiline\r\nnightmare,\r\nbut\r\nwe\r\ncan manage it"}
```