# Response with unwanted new lines appears while encoding array to JSON

Tags: php, json, php-7.0

Having an array printed with `print_r` method:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [item_level] => 0
            [position] => 10
            [parent_position] => 
            [title] => PHP Tutorial
            [qty] => 0
            [comment] => 
            [status] => 
            [unit] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [item_level] => 1
            [position] => 20
            [parent_position] => 
            [title] => Algorithms
            [qty] => 1
            [comment] => 
            [status] => 
            [unit] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 48
            [item_level] => 2
            [position] => 30
            [parent_position] => 20
            [title] => PHP and MySQL Databases
            [qty] => 1
            [comment] => 
            [status] => 
            [unit] => 
        )
)
```

I'm trying to encode it as JSON using either:

```php
json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
json_encode($array);
```

The output in both cases is the following though:

```js
[{"id":"44","item_level":0,"position":10,"parent_position":"","product_id":"","title":"PHP
Tutorial","qty":0,"comment":"","status":"","unit":""},{"id":"46","item_level":1,"position":20,"parent_position":"","title":"Algorithms","qty":1,"comment":"","status":"","unit":""},{"id":"48","item_level":2,"position":30,"parent_position":20,"title":"PHP
and MySQL
Databases","qty":1,"comment":"","status":"","unit":""}]
```

Yes, there are the newline characters put between some, but not all, space-separated words. In Postman, the response arrives broken into multiple lines, the same happens when my frontend gets this kind of response, causing it to report JSON parsing error.

How to transform the array to JSON format properly?

PHP version here is 7.0.33.

Comment: So you have newlines in some of the data in the array. Tidy that up, probably where the array gets created

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264631/php-json-encode-not-escaping-new-lines could be relevant

Comment: I recommend `var_dump()` over `print_r()` as it shows more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to look for any non-printable characters that might have been added on the way, as it was suggested in the comments, but wasn't able to locate any.

Anyway, `pretty printing` solved the issue in a satisfying way:

```php
json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The only thing to be considered, is casting numbers to proper types on arrival to frontend, since `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` prints out all of them as strings (i.e. `{"quantity": "1"}`).

Comment: What you just described is what I call wishful fixing ;/ Instead of nailing down the culprit and then fix whatever it is, you just found some workarounds and now you **hope** all will be fine from now on. Do not go that way.